# Search a String in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, kibana-6, kibana-3

Trying to search for a complete json request in kibana webapp.

Sample
Request body:: 
{"mobileNumber":"***** ","custType":"abc","rejectReasonDesc":"","applicationId":"*****"}

i want to filter only the request with "rejectReasonDesc":"" i.e empty reject reason desc value .

please help on this

[image]

Comment: are you trying to execute an elasticsearch  query in dev tools

Comment: No .. on the kibana ..Added screenshot above

Answer (score 1):

1. Create index pattern to point to your index.
2. Click on Add filter link
3. Select rejectReasonDesc.keyword field  as per below image

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you response. My user do not have access to create index but the logs are categorised under index message.                                                  for Example message : sadsad  Request body:: {"mobileNumber":"***** ","custType":"abc","rejectReasonDesc":"","applicationId":"*****"}                   is there a way to filter the empty rejectReasonDesc

Comment: @dheeraj Keep value box empty. If value is null then choose operator doesnot exist